# Powerapps: Clear/Reset Gallery fields with button

Tags: checkbox, powerapps, inputtext

I have a simple question that I haven't found or understood anywhere on the internet. I'm a novice powerapps user. I would like to click a button and clear all fields (inputText, checkbox, etc) from a gallery. Details: My data source is some excel tables; this gallery (not a collection or a form for god's sake) has some information from my data source (tab_lista). I tried the following command without success:

Mybutton

**OnSelect**

```
ForAll(BrowseGallery1.AllItems;
    If(ThisRecord.Checkbox1.Value = true;Checkbox1.Value = false);;
    ThisRecord.InputText1.Text = ""
)
```

Segue uma imagem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Scraping an answer here and there, I got it! I used context variable.
In the advanced property of both the `checkbox` and the `InputText` I put the following in the `Reset` field.

**checkbox1**

```
ResetCheckbox
```

**TextInput1**

```
ResetinputT1
```

Then I created a button and put the following in the `OnSelect` property:

```
UpdateContext({ResetCheckbox:true});;
UpdateContext({ResetCheckbox:false});;
UpdateContext({ResetinputT1: true});;
UpdateContext({ResetinputT1: false})
```

and it worked!!!